# Migrar clientes do Magento para Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Bom dia, amigos

Estou migrando uma loja toda do *Magento* para o *Woocommerce*, porém não obtive sucesso em migrar os clientes.

Adicionando manualmente, o *woocommerce* não envia para o cliente um e-mail com as informações dele (fiz um teste aqui e não recebi o e-mail com as informações).

É preciso configurar alguma coisa na questão de envio de e-mails? Detalhe que não é a primeira vez que fico sem receber algum e-mail pois anteriormente fiz um pedido teste e não recebi nada também.

Agradeço desde já.